# Check user license assignment in Office 365

Tags: powershell, azure, office365

How do I fix this script.  I am attempting to get license status for a list of users piped in with Import-CSV, and then intern export the results to a separate CSV file.  This is not quite working for me at the moment.  I appreciate your assistance/ suggestions :-)

```
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MSOLService -Credential $cred
$path = "C:\Scripts\Interns.csv"
$users = Import-Csv $path
$users | ForEach-Object` 
{
Get-MsolUser | Select UserPrincipalName, IsLicensed | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\isLicensed.csv"
}
```

Comment: can you post an example of your interns.csv? It's kinda hard to help without knowing anything about the format. whats the output of $users[0]    ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MSOLService -Credential $cred
$path = get-content C:\Scripts\Interns.csv

Foreach ($user in $path){
   $a = get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $user | select userprincipalname, isLicensed
   $licensed = $a.isLicensed
   $u = $a.userprincipalname
   $result = $u +","+ $licensed
   Add-Content c:\Scripts\isLicensed.csv $result
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions however, it doesn't work,                                                                         get-msoluser : User Not Found.  User: jdoe@domain.com.
At line:4 char:10
+        $a = get-msoluser -UserPrincipalName $user | select userprincipalname, isLic ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetUser